# Gaussian Noise Generation with MATLAB

Tags: matlab, signal-processing

I am a Matlab beginner & need to understand what is going on this code. I know   it is for Gaussian noise generation, but what do these variables mean mathematically?

```
N=5000;
W0= [0.1 0.3 0.5 ];
L= length(W0);
input= randn(1,N+L-1);
SNR_DB= 30;
SP=1;
NP=10^(-SNR_DB/10);
noise= sqrt(NP)*randn(1,N);
plot(1:N,noise)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- $N=5000$.
- $W_0$ is a vector $(0.1, 0.3, 0.5)$
- $L$ is the length of $W_0$, i.e. $3$.
- `input` is a $1\times(N+L-1)$ matrix, i.e. a row vector of length $5002$. Its entries are filled with stardard normal (pseudo)random numbers (`randn`). For some curious reason, this vector is not used anywhere.
- `SNR_DB`, `SP` and `NP` are three parameters. Again, the first two parameters are initiated but not used anywhere.
- `noise` is a row vector of length $5000$ whose entries are standard normal random numbers scaled by $\sqrt{NP}$; that is, its entries are normally distributed with mean zero and standard deviation $\sqrt{NP}$.
- The values of the entries of `noise` are plotted in a graph.

For any further questions about Matlab commands, type `help` in the Matlab command window. E.g. `help randn` would tell you the meaning of `randn`.

Comment: You can also use `doc something` which is sometimes more extensive than `help something`.

Answer (score 0):

SNR_DB means "signal to noise ratio in decibels". This is a physics/engineering term of art which is defined as
$$\text{SNR}_{\text{dB}} = 10\log_{10}\left(\frac{\text{signal power}}{\text{noise power}}\right)$$
The author of the script has set the signal power (SP) to 1, and is calculating the noise power (NP) which will result in $\text{SNR}_{\text{dB}} = 30$ (meaning: signal power is 1000 times the noise power).

"Noise power" means the same as "noise variance". The standard deviation is the square root of the variance (power).

Therefore:
$$30 = \text{SNR}_{\text{dB}} = 10\log_{10}\left(\frac{\text{signal power}}{\text{noise power}}\right) = 10\log_{10} \left(\frac{1}{\sigma^2}\right)$$
where $\sigma$ is the noise standard deviation. Dividing both sides by $10$ and then taking $10$ to the power of both sides, this becomes
$$10^3 = \frac{1}{\sigma^2}$$
so $\sigma = \sqrt{1/1000} = \sqrt{NP}$.

Note that $\text{randn}(1,N)$ generates $N$ pseudorandom numbers from a gaussian distribution with mean $0$ and standard deviation $1$ (and variance $1^2 = 1$). Multiplying these numbers by $\sqrt{NP}$ results in $N$ gaussian samples with mean $0$ and standard deviation $\sqrt{NP}$ (and variance $NP$).